# Cut is working column wise in bash

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I am trying to extract information and send it to a DB from a text file which has these lines

```
EndDate=2014-04-08;Time=00:00:49;ID=1144877;AppName=Ad (ba);MetricName=EndUser1;average_network_time=0
EndDate=2014-05-08;Time=00:00:50;ID=1144878;AppName=Ad (qa);MetricName=EndUser/Apdex;score=1.0;s=0;t=0;f=0
```

The script I have written is:

```
var1="EndUser"
var2="EndUser/Apdex"
var6="path to file"

for line in $var6
do

EndDate=`cut -d';' -f1 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo $EndDate
Time=`cut -d';' -f2 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo $Time
ID=`cut -d';' -f3 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo $ID
AppName=`cut -d';' -f4 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo $AppName
MetricName=`cut -d';' -f5 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo $MetricName

if [ "$MetricName" == "$var1" ];then
echo "in If" 
average_network_time=`cut -d';' -f6 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo "avg=$average_network_time"
echo "('$EndDate','$Time','$ID','$AppName','$MetricName','$average_network_time');"
mysql -h servername -u ID -p'pass' name -e "insert into check_copy(EndDate,Time,ID,AppName,MetricName,average_network_time) values ('$EndDate','$Time','$ID','$AppName','$MetricName','$average_network_time');"
fi

if [ "$MetricName" == "$var2" ];then
echo "in If2" 
score=`cut -d';' -f6 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo $score
s=`cut -d';' -f7 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
t=`cut -d';' -f8 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
f=`cut -d';' -f9 $line | cut -d'=' -f2`
mysql -h servername -u ID -p'pass' name -e "insert into check_copy(EndDate,Time,ID,AppName,MetricName,score,s,t,f) values ('$EndDate','$Time','$ID','$AppName','$MetricName','$score','$s','$t','$f');"
fi
```

The output I get is:

```
2014-04-08 2014-05-08
00:00:49 00:00:50
1144877 1144878
Ad (ba) Ad (qa)
EndUser1 EndUser/Apdex
```

Expected ooutput:

```
2014-04-08 00:00:49 1144877 Ad (ba) EndUser1 0
2014-05-08 00:00:50 1144878 Ad (qa) EndUser/Apdex 1.0 0 0 0
```

My problem: It is not getting into the loop itself. May be because it is doing it column wise
I want it to print avg netwrok time value,score,s,t,f for its respective metric names.

Comment: I'm surprised that this produces _anything at all_. `cut -d';' -f1 $line` wouldn't work.

Comment: But it is working and I am getting an output. Any suggestions on what to do for it to work as you say it wouldnt

Comment: I don't see where you the "do" is "done".  Also, you may want to use echo -n to avoid getting newlines.  For the if tests, you should check if you're using the right comparison operator (can strings be == ?). Also, as a recovered cut user, I can tell you the syntax is correct, but this is very much a sed/awk problem – follow the path clement pointed you in.

Comment: In this I forgot to mention the done as this is just a part of my complete script. Yes It equilizes when I do it separately and give an echo statement to check. My problem is with cut as it is doing it column wise of the lines than a line to line looping. It does not get into the if loop itself. But if I do it with 1 line everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If `file` has

```
EndDate=2014-04-08;Time=00:00:49;ID=1144877;AppName=Ad (ba);MetricName=EndUser;average_network_time=0
EndDate=2014-05-08;Time=00:00:50;ID=1144878;AppName=Ad (qa);MetricName=EndUser/Apdex;score=1.0;s=0;t=0;f=0
```

The following `sed` command

```
sed -n -r -e '/MetricName=EndUser;/{s/^EndDate=(.*);Time=(.*);ID=(.*);AppName=(.*);MetricName=(EndUser);average_network_time=(.*)$/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6/gp}'  -e '/MetricName=EndUser\/Apdex/{s/^EndDate=(.*);Time=(.*);ID=(.*);AppName=(.*);MetricName=(EndUser\/Apdex);score=(.*);s=(.*);t=(.*);f=(.*)$/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9/gp}' file
```

will give

```
2014-04-08 00:00:49 1144877 Ad (ba) EndUser 0
2014-05-08 00:00:50 1144878 Ad (qa) EndUser/Apdex 1.0 0 0 0
```

Works with `GNU sed version 4.2.1`. You can generate the `mysql` query directly by modifying the `replacement` part in `s/pattern/replacement/pg`

Comment: Thank you. I use a mac OS and it does not seem to work. I am still trying on modifying and learning on Mac OS keeping the above as reference. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: Whats is your `Mac OS` version?